# SYMBOL_INFO.Register value definition

Tags: winapi, windbg

How is the register member of this strucure in is defined?  The documentation in MSDN is:

**Register**  The register.

How is register defined, and what would be the meaning of the value 0x16 for x86?

```
Local var @ 0x123584 Type _SYMBOL_INFO*
0x02b0e3a8 
   +0x000 SizeOfStruct     : 0x58
   +0x004 TypeIndex        : 6
   +0x008 Reserved         : [2] 0
   +0x018 Index            : 5
   +0x01c Size             : 4
   +0x020 ModBase          : 0x400000
   +0x028 Flags            : 0xd0
   +0x030 Value            : 0
   +0x038 Address          : 8
   +0x040 Register         : 0x16
   +0x044 Scope            : 5
   +0x048 Tag              : 7
   +0x04c NameLen          : 0xc
   +0x050 MaxNameLen       : 0x100
   +0x054 Name             : [1]  "h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the register value corresponds to the [CV_HREG_e enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/a0fcdkb9%28VS.71%29.aspx) so the value 0x16 corresponds to EBP.